# Overlaying 2 histograms by 2 groups in plotly

Tags: r, group-by, plotly, histogram

I have a data.table, and I would like to create an histogram (or barplot) by 2 groups in **plotly**

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

n = 7200
n1 = 4/3*n
n2 = 2*n


dt = data.table(x = sample(rep(c("0-20", "21-40", "41-60", "61-80"), n)),
                group1 = sample(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), n1)),
                group2 = sample(rep(c(0, 1), n2))
)
setorder(dt, x, group1, group2)
dt[, x := factor(x)]
dt[, group1 := factor(group1)]
dt[, group2 := factor(group2)]



ggplot(dt) + geom_bar(aes(x = x, fill = factor(group2)), width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#9c868b", "#038073"), guide = 'none') + guides(legend = 'none') +
  scale_y_continuous(position = 'right') +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(forcats::fct_rev(group1)), switch = 'y') +
  coord_flip(clip = "off")
```

Here is the result I want to have (made with ggplot) and I don't want to use ggplotly(...)

[image]

I do not know if I have to handle data like below to create barplot instead of histogram

```
dt = dt[, .N, by = .(x, group1, group2)]
dt = dcast(dt,
        group1 ~ x + group2,
        value.var = c("N"))
```

Comment: Some "meta" comment: stacking two histograms will cause a step-wise instead of flush baseline of the second histogram. This thwarts the histogram's actual purpose, i. e. the easy visual *comparison* of frequencies via column height / bar length.

Comment: First you say you want this done in plotly and then you say "I don't want to use ggplotly(...)"

Comment: there is a difference in creating the graph entirely using plotly rather than creating it in ggplot and converting it with ggplotly

Comment: @I_O since the purpose of a histogram is to discretize numeric/ratio variables based on frequency ranges and a bar graph is most often used for categorical/nominal frequencies, isn't the questioner's idea to capitalize on Plotly's aggregation of data for histograms? In contrast, Plotly does _not_ inherently count for a bar graph. Would you say the same inadequacy exists in a bar graph?

Comment: @Kat , IMO bar charts and histograms are really valuable (and perhaps even underrated) visualisations. Not least because our visual perception is so skilled at judging height differences ("can I eat that thing, or will it eat me?"), compared to, e. g. angles as in pie charts. For that effect, however, the elements need to share the same baseline (not basestair), which is the case for the bottom, but not for the following histogram(s) of a stack. One of the most challenging arrangements, I find, are colour-coded stacks of fractions.

Comment: I guess it all comes down to the purpose of a visualization... that being to _simplify_ the information or make it less complex, easier to understand... and all that...I'm tracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make something similar in a few lines of code. If you want all the details lined up as you've depicted, it's a 'few more'.

> By the way, I used `set.seed(34)` if you wanted to see the *exact* same plot.

```
# not really what you're looking for
plot_ly(subset(dt, group2 == "0"), type = 'histogram', name = 'group 0',
        y = ~list(rev(group1), x), orientation = 'h') %>% 
  add_histogram(subset(dt, group2 == "1"), name = 'group 1',
                y = ~list(rev(group1), x), orientation = 'h') %>% 
  layout(barmode = 'stack')
```

[image]

(I didn't include the axis title or legend in the image; I'm just trying to highlight the *lack of gap*)

You can always continue to mod this graph toward the desired plot. However, you won't get the gaps you're looking for between the bars.

Alternatively, you could use `subplot` and make a separate plot for each of the unique values used in faceting in your original plot.

```
lapply(1:length(unique(dt$group1)), # for each facet...
       function(k) {
         dt <- subset(dt, group1 == unique(dt$group1)[k])             # find facet data
         p <- plot_ly(dt, type = "histogram", color = ~group2,
                      y = ~x, orientation = 'h', showlegend = F) %>%  # no legend
           layout(barmode = 'stack', bargap = 0)
         assign(paste0('p', k), p, envir = .GlobalEnv)                # put in global env
       })

subplot(p1, p2, p3, nrows = 3, titleX = T, shareX = T) %>%            # assemble facets
  layout(xaxis = list(side = 'top', title = 'count', anchor = 'y1'))  # anchor top plot
```

[image]

With a few more lines of code, you can add the labeling as you see in `ggplot` faceting.

```
lapply(1:length(unique(dt$group1)), # for each facet...
       function(k) {
         message(print(k))
         dt <- subset(dt, group1 == unique(dt$group1)[k])             # find facet data
         p <- plot_ly(dt, type = "histogram", color = ~group2,
                      y = ~x, orientation = 'h', showlegend = F) %>%  # no legend
           layout(barmode = 'stack', bargap = 0,
                  shapes = list(     # like facet plot this is the gray bar behind label
                    type = "rect", xref = 'x', yref = 'paper',     # set plot 'space'
                    y0 = 0, y1 = 1, x0 = -250, x1 = -50,           # rect limits
                    fillcolor = 'lightgrey',
                    line = list(linewidth = 0.0001, color = 'lightgrey') # remove border
                  ),
                  annotations = list(    # like facet plot, this is the facet label
                    showarrow = F, text = unique(dt$group1),          # no arrow; label
                    xref = 'x', yref = 'paper', x = -150, y = .5,     # center of 'rect'
                    xanchor = 'center', yanchor = 'center', textangle = -90 # rotate text
                  ))
         assign(paste0('p', k), p, envir = .GlobalEnv)                # put in global env
       })

subplot(p1, p2, p3, nrows = 3, titleX = T, shareX = T) %>%            # assemble facets
  layout(xaxis = list(side = 'top', title = 'count', anchor = 'y1'))  # anchor top plot
```

[image]